# Why does this CSS produce such a huge layout when displayed on a smartphone?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have this CSS:  https://cal-linux.com/styles/tutorial.css

And a sample page that uses it:  https://cal-linux.com/tutorials/gswc++.html

When I display this on a smartphone  (or when I check it through Google's Mobile friendliness verify service),  the layout looks huge  (badly cropped, instead of reduced to fit the smartphone's screen.

I only use proportional measures  (for example, outsidecontainer's div has width 80%, inside right-most column has min-width 25%).  I'm placing Google Ads in there, but it's a "Responsive" add, which is supposed to adapt to the page's available size and layout.

Any tips on this?  I figured posting the actual links to the pages might be ideal;  but please let me know if a "minimal" instance of code that reproduces the problem would be preferred.

Thanks,

### Cal-linux

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I note here:

1. You use `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` a bit too much.  Those don't respond as well to the resizing especially if you have not specified the width of each item.  Instead either use floats with a clear:both on the container's :after pseudo-element or inline-block.  Either way you should define percent widths for the containers.
2. Your css has a lot of `white-space:nowrap` but doesn't use overflow:auto which forces the element to not resize the content and just stretch its parent container.
3. Aside from that a few places I see a fixed `px` width which makes it more difficult to resize.  It doesn't seem to be your ads.  Although google's script does throw an error about trying to put an ad in an 86px x undefined space.  You can set a fixed `height` or at least a `min-height` to give the script an idea of how big an ad should be placed there.

The easiest solution is to incorporate bootstrap to do the heavy lifting of setting up a grid for what you want.

You can basically do your two column style like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="left-col col-md-11">
     <!--- ALL YOUR CONTENT HERE //-->
  </div>
  <div class="right-col col-md-1">
     <!---Google Ads go Here //-->
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to stick with your own style, by using the code inspector in chrome I was able to get to the following result when resized:
[image]

- I made the tablerow class be a standard `display:block`
- The first column was set to `width:75%; display:inline-block;`
- The second column was set to `width:25%; display:inline-block;`
- The autosize elements changed to `display:block;max-width:100%;   overflow:auto;width:auto;padding:0`
- The div.code blocks were changed to `display:block;white-space:nowrap;width:auto;`

Everything else stays the same pretty much.  That should fix it, however you should note that frameworks like bootstrap help out with mobile sites by making the page columns collapse and go one ontop of another for mobile browsers so that they get maximum space.

Comment: Please bear with me, as I have very limited experience with web development (especially with CSS).   I'm looking at the bootstrap download, and the "minimized" source code is 120+ kilobytes.  According to the w3.org mobile validator, having a markup above 10k or a total (including CSS + images + aux) above 20k makes it less mobile friendly.  CSS only is 120k.....  what am I missing?

Comment: In web development you can optimize the loads. 120k may seem like a lot but it is reused by the cache so you only transmit it once. And at the same time you have a decent framework for pretty much all needs. You can also customize the bootstrap download of all you need is the grid framework. The full framework includes icons and other useful tools

Comment: BTW --- another comment to your initial response;  you show the preview on a desktop browser.  Notice that, as far as I can tell, the page (as originally coded) displays perfectly ok on a desktop.  My "puzzlement" was that the percentages don't seem to kick in on a mobile browser  (on my Android 4.0.4 / Samsung GT-S7560M phone anyway) and the document's width seems to be 4 or 5 times the screen's width.  Is that related to the details you pointed out?

Comment: The true test of responsiveness is not the mobile platform but rather any resolution on a desktop.  If you resize y your browser and the site adapts to the changes well then the site is pretty much ready for anything